# How to create Job object using a template location?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-java-client

We have this api to update a job.

`dataflowService.projects().jobs().update(projectId, jobId, newJob);`

I need to create a `Job` object (in this case the `newJob` object) in a backend java service using a template (I have the GCS template location) which I will later use to update an existing job.

Answer (score 2):

The template API allows creating a new job from a template, but does not support updating a previously running job. The `jobs().update(...)` API is not intended for general use -- instead, use the SDK to create an [update to an existing pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline).

Comment: is there a way to update a job using google apis and not the SDK?

Comment: Not currently. Do you have more details on your use case? Without using the SDK you wouldn't be able to create a new pipeline structure, which means the update wouldn't be any different from the original job.

Comment: Use Case: Continuous Deployment of streaming pipelines. 
Right now, we tried to set the `update` option to true and generating the template. But when launch/create a job using this template. It fails with `The workflow could not be created. There is already an active job`.

Comment: For continuous deployment, what value does a template provide? Rather than creating a template and then running it to update the original job, you could just update the original job directly.

Comment: Templates would allow us to track versions of different builds. This allows for deploy and rollback mechanisms, just like backend service.